# Using "broken" option in animation curves doesn't work for rotation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm making a game using sprite sheets, but I was curious to see if I could animate other sprites into the animation.  Indeed, it is possible, however the animation's curve has to be dealt with, or else you have one part choppy, and the other very smooth.  I found this resource which helped: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/893479/how-to-make-not-smooth-multi-sprite-animation.html

While the "broken" curve works for translation, it seems to be without effect on rotation.
This is what happens instead:

[image]

As you can see the curves are straight, but the animation does not reflect that.

I'm wondering if this is a bug?

I haven't found any other resources mentioning it.  I realize I can simply create another sprite sheet, but it'd be efficient if I could do it in this manner, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting different interpolation modes from context menu of rotation property. **Eeuler angles( Quaternion Approximation )** should be suitable for you

[image]

Comment: I did look into this, but only Eular Angles and Quaternion options are available, and the Quaternion option has similar results.  Are you using Pro?  Or maybe that only works on 3D objects, where as mine is 2D?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7g6V.png

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.3 where this option exists. Also, looks like this a known bug. I've found this thread http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rotation-animation-issue-with-constant-tangents.213868/   and bugreport http://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?705367_3gckb228cf4rl815

Comment: I updated from 5.2 to 5.3, and now Euler Angle interpolation works as intended.  Thanks for your help.